# How do I know the name of validated field?

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation

I need to know the name of field in the isValid method of my ConstraintValidator implementation.

```
@Override
public void initialize(Unique constraintAnnotation) {

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
//do specific query for concrete field
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select l from Location as l where l.trf = :trf");
    query.setParameter("trf", value);
    List results = query.getResultList();
    if (results.size() > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Generally speaking, I have field name in the 'context' parameter.
For example in context.basePath.currentLeafNode. But how I can access 'currentLeafNode'?
Furthermore, I can to pass specific class name with 'payload' attribute

```
@Unique(payload = Trf.class)
```

But how I can access 'payload' array in the 'isValid' method?

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, you create instance field in your validator, then in initialize method you do something like `this.payload = constraintAnnotation.payload();` and access this instance field from the `isValid` method.

Comment: @Bohuslav Burghardt Yes, this approach works fine. But can I do that without 'payload' attribute? As at first part of question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no means to get the property name in the `isValid` implementation of a `ConstraintValidator`. One could image a Hibernate Validator specific feature for this. Some extension to add to `HibernateConstraintValidatorContext`. You could create an issue in https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HV to get some feedback on this.

For now your best bet is probably the payload.